# Using Wordpress Jetpack Json api to return member information

Tags: wordpress, nsurlconnection, nsurlrequest, jetpack

The documentation for Wordpress Jetpack plugin dose not really offer a step by step guide on how to get everything set up for querying your wordpress site using the Json Rest API.

However I have managed to get to the point where I can query my sites posts, which I guess means I have these steps set up correctly.

```
A, set the wordpress site up correctly 
B, installed jetpack correctly and 
C, set up my developers account with wordpress and registered my
app.
```

My goal is to set up a business directory where I can access the user generated data from an iphone application I will write, I plan to use NSURLConnection to send my queries and I will store the returning Json data into CoreData on the phone.

I have set up s2Member on word press which allows people to join my site at $XX.XX cost to them, after payment they can then fill in their account detials which includes a section about their business. i.e. name, address and contact details etc.

I would like to know how to access this user information. For instance I had hoped that I could do a single query which would return to me every single members details that I would then save into coredata/phone cache. However I am not sure how to do this.

What I had though about using was https://developer.wordpress.com/docs/api/1/get/me/ but I'm not sure if this will return the business information I am after and I'm not really sure how to construct the request using the example code on the page

```
cURL

curl \
 -H 'authorization: Bearer YOUR_API_TOKEN' \
 'https://public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v1/me/?pretty=1'
```

How would I turn this into a `NSURLRequest` for my app's `NSURLConnection`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it seems you're trying to figure out how to setup an HTTP request with custom headers. Something like this:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v1/me/?pretty=1"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request addValue:@"Bearer YOUR_API_TOKEN" forHTTPHeaderField:@"authorization"];
```

You then fire off the request using the networking API of your choice (I recommend `NSURLSession` for any new development).

Comment: the authorization part of the curl example is what I am having problems with. where dose that fit into things?

Comment: This is the error I am getting with your code "2013-12-29 23:17:30.578 guideTest[933:c07] <NSMutableURLRequest https://public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v1/me/?pretty=1>
2013-12-29 23:17:32.331 guideTest[933:c07] {
    "error": "authorization_required",
    "message": "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.""

Comment: okay great.. i understand that I just need to figure out where to find my app api token then.. I have a client ID and client secret.. but i canot find the token.

Comment: this worked I had to go through the 0Auth process to get the app token.